# Snakemake-ambiguous rule exception

Tags: exception, rules, snakemake, ambiguous

I got an error message as follows:
Rules base_quality_control_fetal and base_quality_control are ambiguous for the file /data/Fetal_BW_European.txt.gz.
Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
Wildcards:
base_quality_control_fetal: ifetal_basedata=Fetal_BW_European
base_quality_control: ibase_data=Fetal_BW_European
Expected input files:
base_quality_control_fetal: 1-basedata-fetal.sh /data/Fetal_BW_European_meta-NG2019.txt.gz
base_quality_control: 1-basedata.sh /data/Fetal_BW_European_meta-NG2019.txt.gz
Expected output files:
base_quality_control_fetal: /data/results/Fetal_BW_European_meta-NG2019.txt.gz
base_quality_control:  /data/results/Fetal_BW_European_meta-NG2019.txt.gz
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inWCa.png)

But I am it is actually 2 different rules and produce different output files.
Did I make some mistakes? Please help me to check it. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Wu

Comment: Please edit your question. Put the text of your script instead of a picture, add enough formatting. Otherwise your question doesn't meet the requirements and shall be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The message is self explanatory: there are two different rules that can produce the same file: `config["output_path"] + base_data/{ifetal_basedata}.txt.gz` can be resolved to the same filename in both rules.

Comment: Thanks! I give 2 different output path, it sovled.